# TypeORM + TypeScript: migrations are not registered on migration table

Tags: typeorm, ts-node, node.js-typeorm

I am using TypeORM in a Node.js project with ts-node and MySQL. The dev platform is on Windows.
I can perform a complete CRUD on my data, but when I try to do a migration, it doesn't work as expected.

I configured my package.json as shown on [TypeORM site](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/installing-cli):

```
"scripts": {
...
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js" }
```

I configured my `ormconfig.json` as this:

```
{
"type": "mysql",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 3306,
"username": "m3user",
"password": "***",
"database": "m3db",
"synchronize": false,
"logging": false,
"entities": [
  "src/**/models/*.ts"
]
}
```

When I run:

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n PostRefactoring
```

I see my migration file, which is correct (at least in the MySQL part):

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";
export class PostRefactoring1634588948104 implements MigrationInterface {
name = 'PostRefactoring1634588948104'
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`supply\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`netPurchaseCost\` int NULL, \`netShippingCost\` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', \`supplySeconds\` int NULL, \`minQtyOrder\` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`partner\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`businessName\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`address\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`supplyListId\` int NULL, \`stockMovementListId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`stock_movement\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`datetime\` datetime NOT NULL, \`quantity\` int NOT NULL, \`notes\` varchar(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`warehouse_location\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`code\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`movementListId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`warehouse\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`item_warehouse_config\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`isManagedInWarehouse\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`safetyStock\` int NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`uom\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`abbreviation\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`itemListId\` int NULL, \`attrListId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`item\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', \`internalCode\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', \`supplierItemCode\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', \`producerItemCode\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', \`stdAcquisitionMode\` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', \`notes\` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', \`attrListId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`item_attribute\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`netProductionCost\` int NULL, \`netSellingPrice\` int NULL, \`vatPercentage\` int NULL, \`test\` varchar(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`attribute\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`description\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`test\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`itemAttrListId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`user_group\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`isAdmin\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isWarehouseOperator\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isWarehouseManager\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isMesOperator\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isMesManager\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isSystemOperator\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`isSystemManager\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE \`user\` (\`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL, \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL, \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, \`username\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`password\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`name\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`surname\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`email\` varchar(255) NOT NULL, \`hasAcceptedPrivacy\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, \`privacyAcceptanceDatetime\` datetime NULL, \`isEnabled\` tinyint NULL, \`userGroupId\` int NULL, PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)) ENGINE=InnoDB`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` CHANGE \`ID\` \`ID\` int NOT NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP PRIMARY KEY`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`ID\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`id\` int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`spare1\` varchar(255) NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`spare2\` varchar(255) NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`spare3\` varchar(255) NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`createdBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`createdAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`updatedBy\` varchar(255) NOT NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`updatedAt\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`isActive\` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`quantity\` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`notes\` varchar(255) NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`itemId\` int NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`warehouseId\` int NULL`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_623dbc561abc7fade5a85931712\` FOREIGN KEY (\`itemId\`) REFERENCES \`item\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_2cc5be32db1259f44995d0100aa\` FOREIGN KEY (\`warehouseId\`) REFERENCES \`warehouse\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`partner\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_0aee63b67e4a0d4501871e66ed9\` FOREIGN KEY (\`supplyListId\`) REFERENCES \`supply\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`partner\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_c559547d5c903c0820d958b5484\` FOREIGN KEY (\`stockMovementListId\`) REFERENCES \`stock_movement\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`warehouse_location\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_c9fec71c3c83c5209d80b0e4549\` FOREIGN KEY (\`movementListId\`) REFERENCES \`stock_movement\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`uom\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_4135a9616440dc60342f39d80c7\` FOREIGN KEY (\`itemListId\`) REFERENCES \`item\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`uom\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_df6b5325d8028ca9310fcccd0dd\` FOREIGN KEY (\`attrListId\`) REFERENCES \`attribute\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`item\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_48ca3b3bc9f797f8135caa1ecfa\` FOREIGN KEY (\`attrListId\`) REFERENCES \`item_attribute\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`attribute\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_9f5a46f694e4fe566c44f1aa9f0\` FOREIGN KEY (\`itemAttrListId\`) REFERENCES \`item_attribute\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`user\` ADD CONSTRAINT \`FK_2b7a243184e4f1a8b7451c09eb1\` FOREIGN KEY (\`userGroupId\`) REFERENCES \`user_group\`(\`id\`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
}

public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`user\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_2b7a243184e4f1a8b7451c09eb1\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`attribute\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_9f5a46f694e4fe566c44f1aa9f0\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`item\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_48ca3b3bc9f797f8135caa1ecfa\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`uom\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_df6b5325d8028ca9310fcccd0dd\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`uom\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_4135a9616440dc60342f39d80c7\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`warehouse_location\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_c9fec71c3c83c5209d80b0e4549\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`partner\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_c559547d5c903c0820d958b5484\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`partner\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_0aee63b67e4a0d4501871e66ed9\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_2cc5be32db1259f44995d0100aa\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP FOREIGN KEY \`FK_623dbc561abc7fade5a85931712\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`warehouseId\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`itemId\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`notes\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`quantity\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`isActive\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`updatedAt\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`updatedBy\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`createdAt\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`createdBy\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`spare3\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`spare2\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`spare1\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` DROP COLUMN \`id\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD \`ID\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` ADD PRIMARY KEY (\`ID\`)`);
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`stock\` CHANGE \`ID\` \`ID\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`user\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`user_group\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`attribute\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`item_attribute\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`item\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`uom\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`item_warehouse_config\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`warehouse\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`warehouse_location\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`stock_movement\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`partner\``);
    await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE \`supply\``);
}
```

But I do not see the migration in my DB. If I run:

```
SELECT * from migrations;
```

I see an empty set.
When I run:

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:run
```

The result is:

```
query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'm3db' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM `m3db`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
No migrations are pending
```

I checked the case-sensitivity of DB name and username.
Thanks in advance for help!

**Update 1**:

Running

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:show
```

I get the following result:

```
query: SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'm3db' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM `m3db`.`migrations` `migrations` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

**Update 2**:

If I run:

```
npm run typeorm migration:generate -n PostRefactoring
```

without -- I get the following error:

```
Required argumento missing: n
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backendm3@2.0.0 typeorm: `node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js "migration:generate" "PostRefactoring"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the backendm3@2.0.0 typeorm script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\altth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-19T20_16_05_693Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what is the output for `npm run typeorm -- migration:show`? Or can you add command in package.json `"mg:show": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:show",` and try `npm run mg:show`?

Comment: I updated my question with the output.

Comment: can you try not to include `--` in your command? What is the output then?

Comment: Still not working, check Update 2 for details.

Comment: No, i meant to run migration:show, or migration:run without `--`. and not migration:generate

Comment: It does not show anything (migration:show) and does not apply changes (migration:run).